# Detecting mouse proximity in processing.js

Tags: javascript, html, processing, processing.js

I am coding with processing.js. I want the size variable to get greater as the cursor (mouse) approches the ellipse and to get smaller as the cursor moves away from the ellipse. The size should (if possible) be limited between minimum 50 and maximum 200. Is there any way to accomplish that ?

I've looked online, but there doesn't seem to be lots of documentation (at least for what I was searching for) about this.

Here is my code :

```
void setup()
{
// Setting up the page
  size(screen.width, screen.height);
  smooth();
  background(0, 0, 0);
// Declaring the variable size ONCE
  size = 50;
}

void draw()
{
  background(0, 0, 0);

// I want the size variable to be greater as the cursor approches the ellipse and to be smaller as the cursor moves away from the ellipse. The size is limited if possible between 50 and 200

// Here is the variable that needs to be changed
  size = 50;

// Drawing the concerned ellipse
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, size, size);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the distance from the mouse to the ellipse:

```
float distance = dist(mouseX,mouseY, width/2,height/2);
```

Then, you need to convert that distance into a more usable range. We'll call the result `dia`, since `size()` is also the name of a command in Processing. We also want `dia` to get larger as the distance gets smaller.

For both those things, we'll use [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) which takes an input value, it's range, and an output range:

```
float dia = map(distance, 0,width/2, 200,50);
```

When `distance` is 0, `dia = 200` and when `distance` is the width of the screen divided by 2, `dia = 50`.